# Why is this conditional dict comprehension not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this it returns `{}` when I expected a new `dict` containing the keys listed in profile_fields.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import datetime

user = {'email_optin': False, 'paid': 0, 'location': None, 'account_state': 'enabled', 'ip_address': '1.1.1.1', 'modified_timestamp': 1440107582, 'image': None, 'created': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 21, 53, 2, 436540), 'website': None, 'public_key': None, 'last_seen': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 21, 53, 2, 434959), 'full_name': None, 'user_id': 'jk4vv6cucgxtq6s4i3rgmdcwltvva2fl', 'confirmed': False, 'twitter': None, 'email_address': 'h@example.org', 'modified': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 21, 53, 2, 436554), 'password': '$5$rounds=110000$HnkKE5jWtb1I1cps$dOu0PeijD.enkVd85ofpVpI.1p9wpAsx8fLLSENEuQ1', 'github': None, 'created_timestamp': 1440107582, 'subscription_plan': '', 'user_name': 'xdc'}



profile_fields = [
'location,'
'email_address,'
'full_name,'
'github,'
'image,'
'public_key,'
'twitter,'
'user_id,'
'user_name,'
'website'
]

profile = {k:v for k,v in user.items() if k in profile_fields }
print('profile')
print(profile)
```

edit: the above problem was a message that my sixteen hour coding day had come to a close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have put the commas inside the quotes instead of outside. Your list `profile_fields` contains just a single string literal.

Comment: @OP - the `,` goes _outside_ the `'string',` see?

Comment: I think I need to go to bed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can define profile_fields list like

```
profile_fields = [
        'location', 'email_address', 'full_name',
        'github', 'image', 'public_key', 'twitter',
        'user_id', 'user_name','website'
            ]
```

you can use [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your list. It should like this,

```
profile_fields = ['location','email_address','full_name','github','image','public_key','twitter','user_id','user_name','website']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `profile_list` should actually look like this:

```
profile_fields = [
    'location',
    'email_address',
    'full_name',
    'github',
    'image',
    'public_key',
    'twitter',
    'user_id',
    'user_name',
    'website'
]
```

As noted, the commas should be *outside* the quotes that make up the string. You currently have a list with a single element that will never match any of the keys in your `user` dictionary. It's a simple fix.